# Do I need to create surrogate key for my relationship table?

Tags: sql, database-design, doctrine-orm

I've a relationship table for my many-to-many entities.

author_id | book_id

Do I need to add relation_id? I should be able to identify using both id.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Doctrine, try not to think too much on the RDBMS level (at least, not most of the time).

If you have two Entities with a ManyToMany relationship, you should forget about the surrogate key.  In fact, you should pretty much ignore the fact that the relationship table exists.  You simply have two related entity types.

Now, if you need to store metadata about the relationship itself (for instance the date a badge was awarded to a user), you're going beyond a simple ManyToMany, and you need to model that relationship yourself -- by creating a new kind of entity (a UserBadge, for instance).  That entity, of course, would have an id.

You're using an ORM, think about entities, not about tables (most of the time)!

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time in a joinn table like this just setting both as a combined PK is fine.

Answer (score 4):

You never *need* a surrogate key because you can always in principle use some other key instead.

In your question I don't think you mean "relational table", much less "relation". What I think you mean is "a table with more than one foreign key". Tables with more than one foreign key are not different to other tables and the design principles for them don't need to be different either. Choose the keys on the same basis you would for any other tables.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer having a single column auto-inc key on every table.  It makes deleting and updating much simpler.

Comment: Does it?  If you want to delete or update the record stating that author A wrote book B, how would a surrogate help?  How would you even know what the value of the surrogate was without first selecting it using author_id and book_id?

Comment: Instead of delete from table where column1= 'abc' AND column2 = 'xyz' you do delete from table where id = 123.

Comment: Yes I know.  My question is, how do you know the ID you want to delete is 123 without first looking up the row by what you DO know - the author and book?

Comment: When you get all the books by an author, you get ALL the fields.  In an html listbox, you would put the record ID in the value part of each ListItem.  So when you want to delete a row...it's comparatively trivial.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to add a surrogate key. I would not.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here.

You DO need a unique constraint on the book/column combination to prevent duplicates.  You have to do this even if you put on an auto-inc surrogate key.

Second, many frameworks these days don't know how to deal with anything except an integer key, so you may want to ALSO put on the integer column.  But in this case you would need both.

Answer (score 1):

You strictly don't *need* it, but it might be handy while playing on SQL console, especially if both identifiers of the pair are long and tiresome to type.

On the other hand, it breaks 3NF. If you're not careful you can end up with two records with different surrogate keys and same pair of `(book_id, author_id)` values. You'll have two indices to ensure two uniqueness constraints; this will slow down inserts and updates.

Also you might want to avoid an extra column for efficiency. If your table has great many records, having an extra column will make caching it in memory less efficient, and joins using it will be slowed by disk I/O more often.

Comment: Hi, thank you for accurate answer, I'm using Doctrine 2, and I'm not sure I'll be able to use such keys, I'll probably need to add an auto-inc key, however, I've a lot of records (more than 2,000,000)

Comment: You should mention the use of Doctrine2 more prominently in your question (that is, not only in tags), else you'll keep receiving answers that miss the point, like this.

Comment: Adding a surrogate key doesn't violate 3NF. Failing to enforce the compound key on (book_id, author_id) might do.