# Database structure, trying to find primary keys

Tags: mysql

I have a database with the following tables, Member, Paper, Topic, Interest, Associated.

I need a member to register than upload a paper. When they register they state their interests and this should appear on their home screen.

However in my tables interest i have member_id and topic_id, do i need a primary key for this table? As both of those are foreign keys. And with associated i have paper_id and topic_id but again i have no clue as to what the primary keys should be in those tables.

Comment: member_id, paper_id, topic_id, those will be your primaries. in the interest table you wont need primary

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I need to create surrogate key for my relationship table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794120/do-i-need-to-create-surrogate-key-for-my-relationship-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it is a composite primary key

You can check an example here -> http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/z.dir/tip241027/i02create.xml